# How to force facebook to read meta data?

Tags: facebook

When you take a link from a website and then post it in your facebook status it appears to grab the meta data from that page. What Im seeing is if the webpage has a canonical link to another site it seems to grab the meta data from the other site, is there anyway to force facebook to read the meta data from the link you are posting on your facebook feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're explicitly telling Facebook which URL to fetch via the canonical tag or `og:url` meta tag.

If you want some 'temporary' or 'holding' page to accumulate likes, comments, etc, but redirect somewhere else - have that URL return the correct metadata to Facebook, but redirect other clients which arrive at that URL.